# Change MarkerImage Upon Mouse Hover On DataPoint and ChangeBack to when Leaving Datapoint

Tags: data-visualization, vb.net-2010, mschart

I m trying to change the marker image of plotted data points when a user hovers on a datapoint. The code i shown below:

The data point has been changing image when hovered on it but didn't change it back to "Red.png"?

Could anyone figure out why this is not happening?

Thanks.

```
 Private Sub Chart1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Chart1.MouseMove
    Dim result As HitTestResult = Chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)

    If result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
        Chart1.Series(0).Points(result.PointIndex).MarkerImage = "Green.png"

    ElseIf result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.PlottingArea Then
        Chart1.Series(0).MarkerImage = "Red.png"

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figureed out that:
Changing these lines

```
ElseIf result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.PlottingArea Then
        Chart1.Series(0).MarkerImage = "Red.png"
```

To

```
ElseIf result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.PlottingArea Then
            For i = 0 To Chart1.Series(0).Points.Count - 1
                Chart1.Series(0).Points(i).MarkerImage = "Red.png"
            Next
```

Worked...